# AssertionError: all exprs should be Column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I join two PySpark DataFrames as follows:

```
exprs = [max(x) for x in ["col1","col2"]]
df = df1.union(df2).groupBy(['campk', 'ppk']).agg(*exprs)
```

But I get this error:

```
AssertionError: all exprs should be Column
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have imported `max` from pyspark functions so that you are not using python's max.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
exprs = [max(x) for x in ["col1","col2"]]
```

will return character with max ASCII value ie `['o', 'o']`

Refering the correct `max` would work:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> exprs = [F.max(x) for x in ["col1","col2"]]
>>> print(exprs)
[Column<max(col1)>, Column<max(col2)>]
```

Comment: Let me test it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

try below code
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
exprs = [F.max(x) for x in ["col1","col2"]]
print(*exprs)